Debugging MAUI app on iPhone from Visual Studio ARM inside Parrallel Virtual Machine for Mac
I use Parrallels Desktop 20 (55653) for Mac (mine is Macbook Air M3 16GB 512 installed Sonoma).
I installed Visual Studio ARM (64bit 17.11.3 and ITunes 12.13.3.2) on Virtual Win 11 and when plugged in my iPhone for debugging VS just not recognize the device.
I already choose 'Connected to Win (instead of Mac)' and iPhone got recognized by ITune, Explorer, Windows Device Manager Driver as well (i can see the driver Apple mobile device usb composite device & Apple mobile device usb device are there) on this Virtual Machine.
But whenever I try to deploy from Visual Studio as Local Device (it's .NET MAUI iOS project), a pop up "Setup Hot Restart" appear and when clicking Next it just hangs there forever "Waiting for a device to be connected" ...!
Any advice?
Try to connect the phone into Mac mode (do not connect to Win) and then debug using Remote Device debugging ... but the build is super slow & hangs at the Xamarin.iOS.Common.After.targets(321,3): An exception occurred in the task "FindILLink", right after the code signing and provisioning profile done
Updated: After doing all the below, i'll be able to debug remotely, but debug local device still fail
1). In Win: Delete bin/obj folder of the project
2). In Win: Delete %localappdata%\Temp\Xamarin\XMA
3). In Win: Delete %localappdata%\Xamarin\MonoTouch*.*
4). In Mac: Terminal > open "$HOME/Library/Caches/Xamarin" then delete XMA folder
5). Restart both Win & Mac
6). Reconnect Pair to Mac (make sure the Internet is working otherwise monocheck would not work & object not found error would appear).
If above is complicated, maybe just try below first:
3). In Win: Delete %localappdata%\Xamarin\MonoTouch*.*
This will erase all your credential & reset your Pair To Mac. Restart both VM & MAC and Pair to Mac this time, see if it work
